# How to call an UDF using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

How would I express the following code in Scala via the DataFrame API?

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("/input").registerTempTable("data")
sqlContext.udf.register("median", new Median)
sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |SELECT
    |  param,
    |  median(value) as median
    |FROM data
    |GROUP BY param
""".stripMargin).registerTempTable("medians")
```

I've started via

```
val data = sqlContext.read.parquet("/input")
sqlContext.udf.register("median", new Median)
data.groupBy("param")
```

But them I'm not sure how to call the `median` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `callUDF`

```
data.groupBy("param").agg(callUDF("median", $"value"))
```

or call it directly:

```
val median = new Median
data.groupBy("param").agg(median($"value"))

// Equivalent to
data.groupBy("param").agg(new Median()($"value"))
```

Still, I think it would make more sense to use an `object` not a `class`.

Comment: Good point about object instead of class, I've only used class because I copied the implementation from the java test samples and didn't think about the object.

Comment: I'm curious, are you trying to compute exact median using UDAF?

Comment: yeah. Was an experiment, might just go with pure scala because you'll have to store all values anyway.

Comment: Interesting. Did you use an array as a buffer?

Comment: a sparksql array. Dead slow. Switched to Scala gain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is extremely helpful. I've been trying to create an UDAF that returns an `ArrayType(DoubleType)` and I couldn't  figure out which part is actually failing on runtime. Turns out data has to be extracted as a `Array[Any]` and wrapped with `ArrayData`: `def evaluate(buffer: Row) = new GenericArrayData(buffer.getAs[Seq[Any]](0).toArray)`